# Draw average line of scatter plot with matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to fit an average line in a scatter plot with matplotlib. All im getting is this.

[image]

But I want it like this green line

[image]

I have tried the following two snippets for fitting the curve:

```
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r-")
```

and

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
  return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, residual)
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
```

Comment: With your `poly1d` approach, I think you want `p(x)` in the plot and not `p(y)`.

Comment: Edited. Yes it is supposed to be p(x). But still I'm not getting the line I want :(

Comment: Then you need to make an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run that shows the same problem (without the million points you plot).

Comment: The reason you need an mcve here is from what you show, the red line could actually be the correct fit. Looking at your plots, **either the green line or the red line could be the correct fit**, depending on the distribution and density of the points in the big mass, so it's completely unclear what the problem is.

Comment: The red curve is correct according to data. The data was huge and I misinterpreted with my eyes. @tom10 Should I delete the question?

Comment: Great! Good to know, and thanks for posting. I'm not an expert on whether it should be deleted.  As I see it: 1) it's not really a programming question; but, 2) I'd like to see your data with a density plot instead of the point cloud, so if you did that and wrote it up as an answer, I think it would be informative and possibly help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 4):

As you no provide data I made my own and I've tried this:

```
N = 10000
xr = np.linspace(-1,6,N)
yr = -1*(np.ones(N)-1+xr) + 10*np.random.rand(N)
x = np.concatenate((xr[0:3800],xr[4900:]))
y = np.concatenate((yr[0:3800],yr[4900:]))

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r-")
plt.scatter(x,y, s=2)

plt.show()
```

```

and this is the output I have, which is the expected output:

[image: Scatter and plot]

If you can share a piece of your data I could test it as well.

Comment: But this is the exact same code for the fit that the OP is using that they say doesn't work.  What you're really doing for the OP is providing an mcve, which is nice, but it's not an answer (which is why the OP needs to provide the mcve).

Comment: Thanks man. I misinterpreted the data with my eyes. The red line I got is the correct fit. Thanks to your code I could better perceive it!

Comment: Give @gustavovelascoh a medal!